# Distinguish between Apple's Mac App Store Certificates

Tags: xcode, certificate, code-signing, mac-app-store

Can someone explain to me the differences between these Certificate types shown in my profile in Apple Developer page?

```
Developer ID Application
Mac Installer
Mac App
Mac Development
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Developer ID" certificate is used for code signing a Mac app that is distributed outside the Mac App Store (i.e. from your website). It is used when exporting an Archived build of your app for distribution.

The "Mac Installer" and "Mac App" certificates are used for code signing your Mac app for distribution through the Mac App Store.

The "Mac Development" certificate is used for code signing your Mac app during the development stage of an app destined for the Mac App Store.

Comment: Why "Mac Development" certificate is needed during development ? Thank you.